# How to change rooms easily in socket.io?

Tags: socket.io

How to move from one room to another using socket.io. In the way that the users leaves previous room and joins to the new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/), you can use the `join` and `leave` methods, so 
there's no combined function for this, but you can make one yourself:

```
const moveRoom = (socket, from, to) => {
  socket.leave(from);
  socket.join(to);
}
```

Usage:

```
moveRoom(socket, 'oldRoom', 'newRoom');
```

Get [all rooms](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-rooms) the client is in:

```
let rooms = Object.keys(socket.rooms);
```

You may want to check out the [Socket.IO Emit cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Is there any way to get the previous room?  I am using React.js with Node.js in my project, for now I have found a way to solve this problem by leaving the room in the componentWillUnmount()

Comment: You can use `socket.rooms` to get all the rooms the client is in.